# select values of one field where another field equals a value in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Table as follows

```
 Table

id  busid  stopid
1    1      1
2    2      1
3    3      1 
4    1      2 
5    2      2
6    4      2
```

One column has bus ids and another has stop ids. For instance if I want to take a bus from stop A to Stop B. I will naturally try to find all the common buses that go from stop A to Stop B.

**My approach**

So for example if i want to find all the bues that go from stopid 1 to stopid 2. I CAN clearly see that busid 1 and busid 2 would be the correct answer.

So basically i want to get the all the busids where stopid = 1 and stopid = 2.

I was stuck on how to do this query in rails.

For instance if i do Table.where("stopid = ? AND stopid = ?",1,2) 
This is invalid. So i was wondering what is the correct way of doing the query i described above? I have looked [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields) but did not find any similar example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
  Table.where(stopid: [1,2]).pluck(:busid)
```

It will generate a query like:

```
 SELECT busid FROM tables WHERE (tables.stopid IN (1,2))
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Where can i find documentation about such advance query examples? So in future i can use it as refrence and learn more

Comment: @Learner, You can learn a lot from [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)